# when are two topological spaces homeomorphic?

Tags: general-topology

X and Y are topological spaces. If X is homeomorphic to a subspace of Y and Y is homeomorphic to
a subspace of X then X and Y are homeomorphic. Is this statement true ? justify

I know this is true but am unable to justify it. I tried to construct a homeomorphism but failed.

Comment: What you know is false.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

$\mathbb{R}$ is homeomorphic to (0,1) which is a subspace of $[-1,2]$ and $[-1,2]$ is homeomorphic to $[-1,2]$ which is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$. But $[-1,2]$ is compact and $\mathbb{R}$ is not so they are not homeomorphic.